# Fantasy novel. Boy's father is killed by bear, taken in by father-figure in charge of King's army

Tags: story-identification, magic

The book(s) I'm looking for is a young adult book and part of a series about a boy/young man who leaves his grandparents house to go off to school. The book was set in a different world (similar to medieval times), and the boy lived with his grandparents, because his father was killed by a bear. All he has left of his father is a blue stone necklace. The necklace seemed to stop the boy's power whenever he tried to use it and burns his chest.

Whilst he's travelling, he meets a man who saves him and becomes his father figure. School doesn't work out, because the school was biased against him. The boy was the only person who came from a poor background, and he was therefore treated differently. He got into a fight with a fellow student who provoked the fight, but the boy was punished.  (I think it was a merchant or trader school?) He joins the man who is now his father figure who has come to be in charge of the king's army.

When he joins the king's army, he meets the king's daughter, who is meant to marry another man. He likes her, but she is 'in love' with the man she is meant to marry.

The boy is also able to fight now because of what the man has taught him. I think the man's name was Blaize or Blaise(?).

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you can remember more. What powers did he have? Was the setting modern/sword'n'sorcery/medieval? Did you read the book in English? When did you read the book? What makes you think this is a fantasy novel? Why didn't school work out for the boy? Why was the necklace important? Were there any other significant figures (love interest, perhaps)? Was this a young-adult book or was it more aimed at adults?

Comment: The book was part of a series and in the ones I read his powers were not specified only that whenever he tried to use them the necklace his father gave him would burn his chest and the pain would stop him. It was set in a world that didn't exist but would've resembled medieval times. School didn't work out because the people that ran the school were biased against him because he was the only pupil from a poor background. He got into a fight which was provoked by another student who was wealthy and the school kicked him out. he likes the princess who he met through the army. Young adult.

Comment: I knew you remembered more :-P Now edit that into the question!

Comment: Can you remember what his powers were? Elemental magic? Runes? Psychic?

Comment: Not [Chronicles of Ancient Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_Ancient_Darkness)? It has a boy/young man whose father is killed by a bear and who then goes travelling, but doesn't seem to match the school element.

Comment: No everytime he got close his necklace would burn and no I looked it up and it's not but thank you anyway!